# UIView with long text UILabel could not display text that out of screen height

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

Hey Im new to IOS development, here is the situation, I have UIView displaying a long text with UILable, actually the text is somehow long and the exceed the screen size, but the UIView  don't have a scrollbar or other control to drag down to view the text, is there any ways to do that? [image]

Thanks!

Comment: Use UITextView instead of UIlabel. It has a scrollbar by default

Comment: is there any ways to make UITextView not scroll and also could drag down to view text?

Comment: Why do want to avoid scroll of UITextView? In that case you need to have scroll in your main view itself Or adjust the font size of UItextView in order to fit within the available frame

Comment: Thanks Ratikanta! I want to have scroll in main view, how can I make it? add main frame height?

Comment: Add scroll view to your self.view and give the appropriate contentSize

Comment: Great! I still has an issue, if I put an imageview and another view like webview through xib and the total height exceed the screen height , why the view would auto have scroll and no need to add it manually?

Comment: Sorry not getting it. Please clarify

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. Hmm. let's say in a xib file, I put an ImageView and make the height 240, and then put a webview below, and the height of webview is 400. so the height of these two elements is 640, and it exceed the normal iphone screen's height. When in the simulator if the imageview and webview have content in it, I can see a scroll bar in the right of the screen, but I didn't add it in the xib file.  is it clear for you?

Comment: if the content size is more than the available size then scroll bar would appear by deafault

Comment: so if I program set the content size of the mainview higher than the available size, it will show scroll bar, and no need to add another scrollview? or it only take effect by modifying xib file?

Comment: You can not set the contentSize of a view.First you should add a scrollview to the self.view and then add all other views as subviews of the scroll view(either in Xib or programmatically). Finally set the desired contentSize of the scroll view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [UITextView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html) instead of `UILabel`. You can disable UITextView for editing like this.

```
txtview.editable = NO;
```

`UITextView` will automatically add scroll if the text is long then UITextView frame.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I changed to use UITextView, but it become scrollable, if I set scrollEnabled to NO, it also like the UILabel before. is there any ways to make it not scroll and also could drag down to view text?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do, decrease the height of the `UIView` in which the `UILabel` is , also use `UITextView` instead of `UILabel`.